# Update from Angular 7 to Angular 9 leads to an error

Tags: angular, angular9

[image]The project is compiling successfully but I am getting this error:

> core.js:24350 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: When writing a question, please be brief and use formatting. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section for more details.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to know the solution to your problem with the information you provided. If you input your versions on the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/), it will give you a list of things you need to do to upgrade successfully.

Be advised, it is a good idea to upgrade one version at a time. In other words, in going from Angular 7 to Angular 9, you should first upgrade to Angular 8. Only after ensuring that everything works as expected should you upgrade to Angular 9. This will help narrow down any errors you might be receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You should first update your Angular project from v7 to the latest Angular 8 patch release, next, update to Angular 9 using the following command:

```sh
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

These are the steps:

Step 1 - Preparing and Navigating to your Project
Step 2 - Identifying the Used Angular Version in The Project
Step 3 - Identifying how To Upgrade
Step 4 - Updating from Angular 7 to v8
Step 5 - Updating from Angular v8.2.3 to The Latest Angular 9 Version
Step 6 - Testing the App

You can follow this [tutorial](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular/upgrade-angular-8-7-to-angular-9-with-cli-ng-update/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the update issue, please follow the link calmly, [How to update from 7 to 9](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:9.0)

```sh
ng update @angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7
```

then,

```sh
ng update @angular/cli@8 @angular/core@8
```

lastly

```sh
ng update @angular/cli@9 @angular/core@9
```